# Multiple objects sent to datatables, initialize how?

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, datatables

I'm using datatables with serverside processing. I need to send extra data to the client since I will be needing it to populate my filters.
My core data which i want to display in the table is a list with dictionaries.

When I just send that list this code works:

```
$('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "/TestData/data-source",
"columns": [
    { "data": "thing1",
      "searchable": true},
    { "data": "thing2",
     "searchable": true},
     ...
    { "data": "link",
     "searchable": false,
     "orderable": false},
],
```

I now want to send extra data and still be able to just display these items.

The new JSON will look like this:

```
{'objlist': [{'thing1': '1thing1', 'thing2': '1thing2'},
{'thing1': '2thing1', 'thing2': '2thing2'}], 
'select':[list1, list2]}
```

Might be some typos there but it will be a dict with two objects. One which is a list of dicts, and one which is a list of lists.

How can I initialize my datatable to use the objlist parameters like it did before without the extra object? And how can i reach the values in the select object?

Edit here:

```
"initComplete": function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
```

This is the code which populates my select right now. I want to change it to use the lists from my select object for the different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've been stuck on this problem for a while, but I've finally figured out how to do this. Sort of.

First of all how do you send and get hold of additional data sent from the server?
I did this by not putting the extra data in the data tag that is sent to the DataTable. This is how I sent it:

```
 {'draw': '1',
  'recordsTotal': 13,
  'recordsFiltered': 13,
  'selects': [[1thing1, 2thing1], ['1thing2, 2thing2']],
  'data': [{'thing1': '1thing1', 'thing2': '1thing2'},
           {'thing1': '2thing1', 'thing2': '2thing2'}
  ],
```

Then on the client side you can get hold of the JSON data with this:

```
"initComplete": function (data) {
        var selects = data.json.selects;
```

the data I sent from the server was hidden within data.json.

For my second problem, how to use this knowledge to populate two selects dynamically I used this code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var testtable = $('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: '/TestData/data-source',
        data: function (data) {
            var min = parseFloat( $('#min').val());
            var max = parseFloat( $('#max').val());
            var testselect = $( "#test-filter" ).val();
            var gearselect = $( "#gear-filter" ).val();
            data.min = min;
            data.max = max;
            data.testselect = testselect;
            data.gearselect = gearselect;
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "PAnr",
          "searchable": true},
        { "data": "gear",
         "searchable": true},
        { "data": "ratio",
         "searchable": true},
        { "data": "oiltype",
         "searchable": true},
        { "data": "oiltemp",
         "searchable": true},
        { "data": "link",
         "searchable": false,
         "orderable": false},
    ],
    "initComplete": function (data) {
        var selects = data.json.selects;
        var test = selects[0];
        var gear = selects[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            var option = '<option value="'+test[i]+'">'+test[i]+'</option>'
            $(option).appendTo("#test-filter");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < gear.length; i++) {
            var option = '<option value="'+gear[i]+'">'+gear[i]+'</option>'
            $(option).appendTo("#gear-filter");
        }
    }
    });
    $('#test-filter').change(function(table){
        testtable.draw(false);
    });

    $('#gear-filter').change(function(table){
        testtable.draw(false);
    });

    $('#min').on('keyup', function(table){
        testtable.draw(false);
    });

    $('#max').on('keyup', function(table){
        testtable.draw(false);
    });
});
```

And in my HTML I have this:

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                    <label>Test</label>
                    <select id="test-filter" class="form-control">
                        <option value="None"></option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                    <label>Gear</label>
                    <select id="gear-filter" class="form-control">
                        <option value="None"></option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="range-filter form-group col-lg-3">
                    <div class="ratio-range col-lg-5">
                        <label>Min Ratio</label>
                        <input type="text" id="min" class="form-control" name="min">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ratio-range col-lg-5">
                        <label>Max Ratio</label>
                        <input type="text" id="max" class="form-control" name="max">
                    </div>
                </div>
```